# Is Lubuntu Daily Build on 15-04-2014 = Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, iso, 14.04, zsync

This question is in 2 parts

### 1st Part

My internet connection is slow (5KBps) and I will download **Lubuntu 14.04** on another fast internet connection from my dad's office. This week is full of holidays and the only working day is tomorrow (15-04-2014).

**Lubuntu 14.04** will release on **17-04-2014** which is a holiday in Kerala, India. So, I would like to download **14.04** version tomorrow (15-04-2014).

So is the [Lubuntu daily build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/) of the date **15-04-2014** equals to the **Lubuntu 14.04** version which releases on 17th April. Some little changes on the 16th April version to the 17th day official version is not important.

### 2nd Part

Also, If I download the **.iso** file of **Lubuntu 15th April Version** (using fast internet) and on 17th April using **[zsync](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/)**, I download the latest version to the local file (15th April Lubuntu) on slow internet connection, Will the changes that would be downloaded be too sized or less sized ?

Comment: Download it the next coming week. The iso images won't go anywhere :-)

Comment: @Aditya I can't wait to try Ubuntu 14.04. I just can't stand it. I'm currently using 10.04 and would really like to switch to a new better version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the Lubuntu Daily .iso may not be the final release but once installed it will automatically update itself to the final on the day itself...  I have been using Lubuntu 14.04 beta 2 and with the daily updates will have the final release on the day itself also...

Comment: Does the updates take too much time or will the updates be too much sized ?

Comment: It all depends on what is being updated...  Remember that 14.04 is an LTS release and supported for 5 years, so within that 5 year period many updates can be installed for the final release let alone the daily build...